# Redefining logging root logger

Tags: python, logging

At my current project there are thousand of code lines which looks like this:

```
logging.info("bla-bla-bla")
```

I don't want to change all these lines, but I would change log behavior. My idea is changing root logger to other `Experimental` logger, which is configured by ini-file:

```
[loggers]
keys =  Experimental

[formatter_detailed]
format = %(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(levelname)s %(module)s:%(lineno)d:  %(message)s

[handler_logfile]
class = FileHandler
args = ('experimental.log', 'a')
formatter = detailed

[logger_Experimental]
level = DEBUG
qualname = Experimental
handlers = logfile
propagate = 0
```

Now setting the new root logger is done by this piece of code:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(path_to_logger_config)
logging.root = logging.getLogger('Experimental')
```

Is redefining of root logger safe? Maybe there is more convenient way?

I've tried to use google and looked through stackoverflow questions, but I didn't find the answer.

Comment: First.  Did this work?  Do you have an actual problem?  Second.  Define "more convenient" Two lines of code seems like very convenient.  How more much convenient can you imagine?

Comment: It works! But I suspect, this looks like a hack. "More convenient" means: "using some standard feature of logging module". Sorry.

Comment: Good man! Formatting is awesome.

Comment: "using some standard feature of logging module"?  You **are** using the standard features of the logging module.  What more standard feature could you use?  Are you hoping there's an undocumented copy of this exact configuration in the package?

Comment: if you wanted just to rename the root logger from hardcoded 'root', you could set undocumented `name` attribute: `logging.root.name = 'myapp'` or `logging.getLogger().name = 'myapp'`

Answer (score 26):

You're advised *not* to redefine the root logger in the way you describe. In general you should only use the root logger directly for small scripts - for larger applications, best practice is to use

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

in each module where you use logging, and then make calls to logger.info() etc.

If all you want to do is to log to a file, why not just add a file handler to the root logger? You can do using e.g.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(filename='experimental.log', filemode='w')
    main() # or whatever your main entry point is called
```

or via a configuration file.

**Update:** When I say "you're advised", I mean by me, here in this answer ;-) While you may not run into any problems in your scenario, it's not good practice to overwrite a module attribute which hasn't been designed to be overwritten. For example, the root logger is an instance of a different class (which is not part of the public API), and there are other references to it in the logging machinery which would still point to the old value. Either of these facts could lead to hard-to-debug problems. Since the logging package allows a number of ways of achieving what you seem to want (seemingly, logging to a file rather than the console), then you should use those mechanisms that have been provided.

Comment: "You're advised..." Where?  What's the problem caused by this?  The rest of the answer "In general..." is excellent.  But that first sentence would benefit from some supporting evidence or documentation.

Comment: `logging.root` is of the class `logging.RootLogger`, not `logging.Logger`. These classes mostly behave the same way, but you may encounter a different behavior in some cases. And some type checkers might raise a warning as well.

Comment: It can very well be useful to override root logging. For example when you want also third party modules to log in your structured format.

Comment: @MKesper You can achieve that without redefining the root logger - all logging output is done by handlers the application developer configures, and well-designed libraries shouldn't do any logging output by themselves.

Comment: @VinaySajip You're right. Better to traverse the handlers if it's needed (think gunicorn / uvicorn).

Answer (score 5):

`logger = logging.getLogger()` 
Leaving the name empty will return you the root logger.

`logger = logging.getLogger('name'）` 
Gives you another logger.